# stop scrolling inside fixed div

Tags: html, scroll, fixed, sticky

I have 2 divs (one is fixed, the other one is relative)
I was implementing a scrolling behavior inside the fixed one ... scrolling along with the page. What i want to do more is when the div inside fixed one is scrolled to the bottom this should stop scrolling, only the page should continue scroll.
I do not know if i was very clear so that's why i create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfp6fhg6/).

```
<style>

body {
  background-color:#dddddd;
  margin: 0;
}

#mainDiv{
    top: 120px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#leftDiv{
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #DBEAED;
    height: 300px;
    top: 1em;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#rightDiv{
    width: 68%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #FBE9DD;
}
#filters{
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
            function scrollFunction() {
                var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
                var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0);;

                $('#filters').css("margin-top", -top);
            }
        });
 </script>
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="leftDiv">
        <div id="filters">
            <p>XX 1</p><p>XX 2</p><p>XX 3</p><p>XX 4</p><p>XX 5</p><p>XX 6</p><p>XX 7</p><p>XX 8</p><p>XX 9</p><p>XX 10</p><p>XX 11</p><p>XX 12</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv">
        Here is PLP page
        <p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p>
        <p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p>
        <p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p><p>a</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is more than welcome. Thanks !!!
ps. X12 should stick to the end of blue area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undersand correctly, make it so that `top` has a maximum value of `$('#filters').height()-$('#leftDiv').height()`, which is as far as you want filters to scroll. Further, to make it be able to change directions gracefully, rather than set the margin of `#filters` equal to scroll top, we have to instead increment and decrement the value as we scroll

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
    var filterMargin = 0;
    maxTop = $('#filters').height() - $('#leftDiv').height();
    lastTop = 0;

    function scrollFunction() {

        var doc = document.documentElement, body = document.body;
        var top = (doc && doc.scrollTop || body && body.scrollTop || 0);

        filterMargin = -parseInt($('#filters').css("margin-top"));

        var diff = top - lastTop;

        filterMargin += diff;
        //make sure the margin value stops when the scrolling stops,
        //otherwise the scrolling physically stops but the value keeps growing
        filterMargin = filterMargin < 0 ? 0 : filterMargin;
        filterMargin = filterMargin > maxTop ? maxTop : filterMargin;
        console.log(top, maxTop, filterMargin, top - lastTop);
        $('#filters').css("margin-top", -filterMargin + 'px');
        lastTop = top;
    }

});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nfp6fhg6/5/

Comment: Yes, this is half way done. I didn't mention (because i was thinking is obvious) but if i scroll to the end of big page and start scrolling up again i want also the div inside the fixed one to scroll immediately , not to wait until reach to old position where stop scrolling.

Comment: it should already be doing that, is it doing something different>

Comment: no, if i scroll bottom of the page and then start scrolling up the div with id="filter" not start scrolling up immediately.

Comment: oh. I don't understand why you would want that

Comment: because the div (id="filter") will be a menu, if i have a lot of content on the div (id="rightDiv") then is frustrating scrolling up a lot of content to see the first menu items again.

Comment: yeah but if you scroll way down the right menu, then slightly scroll back up, you will be at the top of the left menu while still being in the  middle of the right menu, which seems weird

Comment: i think is not weird at all i will have access to the menu very easy. if you can help me ... please do.

Comment: i'd love to help, but I'm stuck :)

Comment: oh, ok ... thanks anyway for your time and help so far.